# Term for type of mask

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the term for [this](http://www.benatskemasky.cz/image/cache/002-500x500.jpg)? In my language we have a special word for it, not just *mask*.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the word for it in your language? There are many people here who are multilingual, I for example understand Slovak, Czech, Polish and Russian quite well. The image you linked is from a Czech site, so I guess your native language is Czech?

Comment: It's commonly called a masquerade mask. Domino (as in the answer below) is a technical term, but I've never heard it used in this context.

Answer (score 5):

I'd call that a [domino](http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1097&bih=663&q=domino+mask&gbv=2&oq=domino+mask&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2002l4027l0l4434l11l7l0l1l1l0l209l825l1.3.1l5l0) or a [domino mask](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/domino). If you're looking for a special term in English for a domino mask with feathers, I think you're flat out of luck.